# Android formating number on EditText, cause of clear that

Tags: android

When I try to format entered number on EditText that case of cleared input box

```
formatter                  = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
transfer_amount.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

transfer_amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        String yourFormattedString = formatter
                .format(Long.parseLong(charSequence.toString().replace(",", "")));
        transfer_amount.setText(yourFormattedString);
        finish_chosen_ewallets.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        calculate.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_forms_button_actions));
        chosen_ewallets_message.setText("");
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
});
```

and My Layout for EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/transfer_amount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000"/>
```

Full Stack Error on LogCat:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:878)
at android.view.View.addFocusables(View.java:6157)
at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextInputFocus(FocusFinder.java:100)
at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:83)
at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:639)

at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:6060)
at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:5417)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1048)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1002)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3467)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
at com.mahdi.androidapplication.mahdipaymentservice.UI.Activities.ActivityTransferMoney.ActivityTransferMoney$2.onTextChanged(ActivityTransferMoney.java:184)
at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3550)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
at com.mahdi.androidapplication.mahdipaymentservice.UI.Activities
```

I dont know really whats problem which i cant implementing this simple fueate.

Comment: Refer this link - `https://github.com/pablo/NumberTextWatcher` and `http://blog.roshka.com/2012/08/android-edittext-with-number-format.html`

Comment: @rushankshah this link `http://blog.roshka.com/2012/08/android-e‌​dittext-with-number-‌​format.html` not correct

Comment: it is correct . I am able to open it. Checkk your URL.

Comment: @rushankshah for that i get this message `Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist. ` , how can i use this `NumberTextWatcher` class ?

Comment: You can refer the github.

Comment: You can use it like `editText.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(editText));`

Comment: @rushankshah not working on my application i get this error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0` when i repeating digit `1`

Comment: Can you show me your code?

Comment: @rushankshah I'm using your refer code as : `myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(myEditText));` I get error in this line of class `et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);`

Comment: @rushankshah and after using your refer code, my editText clear afeter formating ?? when i remove this line`et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);`

Comment: Have to check it. Will check this code

Answer (score 0):

Hi this works for me :

```
    public class exampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        final DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        setContentView(editText);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String yourFormattedString = formatter
                        .format( Long.parseLong(s.toString().replace(",", "")));
                Log.e("yourFormattedString ", yourFormattedString);
                editText.setText(yourFormattedString);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Avoid declaring new Objects each time the text change, is unecessary memory waste. Hope it helps !

Comment: Unfortunately i get error sir, my post full updated with your code, problem is on this line of my code: `transfer_amount.setText(yourFormattedString);`